# How to authenticate user who will be accessing my website hosted on bluemix via facebook login

Tags: facebook, ibm-cloud

I did purchase a domain from bigrock and hosted it on bluemix & have used node.js bolierplate + mongodb as a service. It's hosted fine,but now I need to autheticate user via facebook.I searched on google and found that we have facebook API for this, but I am not sure how to use it on domain hosted on bluemix.Can someone please provide me any reference to use this?Currently i dont see any option to use fb api on it...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use Single Sign On Service provided on bluemix dashboard to authenticate user of fb.

You can follow below link to sort out this issue:

http://heidloff.net/nh/home.nsf/article.xsp?id=11.12.2014081049NHEAFB.htm

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add single sign on service as which is provided by bluemix as service binding to get user authentication via facebook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to try single sign on authentication provided by bluemix.

Below is the getting started link with this:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted

You can easily implement fb login using this option.